# pars JSON in Budibase

Tags: budibase

may data structure is weird and I don't have access to change it server side. I have a table with different columns. This table has  a column with the name of the store and some of my data are stored in this column in JSON format ({"phone":"0000","file":"hhhh","State":"55555","code":"5667","agent":"Agent9"}).
now I want to know if there is any way to parse the parameter column and have each of these key/value in a separate column.
I tried these two solutions but got an error

1. {{#with (helpers.parseJSON parameters)}}
   {{phone}}
   {{/with}}
2. {{(helpers.parseJSON parameters).phone}}